# Error with Python - trying to find changes on a webpage

Tags: python, html, monitor

I have question about my Python Code.

I have this code that is trying to find changes on a webpage by making a json file and comparing to see if there any changes every 5 seconds but I am getting this error. I think everything else in the code should work.. How do I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\binance-getmarketsalert-master\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    before_set = set([market['symbol'] for market in before['result']])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The code is this:

```
import time
from smtplib import SMTPException

def build_pair_string(pairs):
    pair_string = ""
    for pair in pairs:
        pair_string += pair + "\n"

    return pair_string

while True:     
    try:
        with open('markets.json', 'r') as current_markets:
            before = json.loads(current_markets.read()) 
    except IOError:
        before = requests.get('').json()
        with open('markets.json', 'w') as current_markets:
            current_markets.write(json.dumps(before))
        print("First run... Getting initial market data.")

    after = requests.get('').json()

    new_set = after_set - before_set

    if not new_set:
        print('No changes.. Waiting 5 seconds')
        time.sleep(5)   
    if new_set:
        with open('markets.json', 'w') as current_markets:  
        duration = 500  # millisecond
        freq = 440  # Hz
        winsound.Beep(freq, duration)   
        print('Binance has added the following pairs:')
        new_list = []
        for pair in new_set:
            new_list.append(pair)  # = [item for item in pair]
        print(new_list)

        sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
        receivers = ['receiver@gmail.com']

        message = """
    Binance added {}
        """.format(build_pair_string(new_list))

        try:
            smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com:465')
            smtpObj.login('example@gmail.com','password')           
            print("\nSuccessfully sent email")
        except SMTPException as e:
            print(e)
            print("\nError: unable to send email")

        logging.critical('Waiting 5 seconds. New coin was listed')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I added [0] so it is now like this

`requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices').json()[0]`

and am getting this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\binance-getmarketsalert-master\test.py", 
    line 28, in <module>
        before_set = set([market['symbol'] for market in before['ETHBTC']])
    KeyError: 'ETHBTC'`

Comment: `after` and `before` are lists of dictionaries. To access the dictionary you need to do something like `before_set = set([market['symbol'] for market in before])`. `'ETHBTC'` is a dictionary value, not a key. You can't access dictionary values like this. I can help more if you explain what this line is trying to achieve.

Comment: Upon running the script, it will take a snapshot of the website and store it in markets.json. 5 seconds later, it will take another snapshot. Before_set gets all the "symbols: xxxx" in the json and after_set gets them 5 seconds later. If there are new "xxxx", it will be able to tell by subtracting all the after_set with the before_set.

Comment: Yup. Then ignore my comment about the `[0]` and just use `before_set = set([market['symbol'] for market in before])` and similarly for `after_set` as `after_set = set([market['symbol'] for market in after])`. Then you can subtract the sets and find any new symbols that have come up.